# CompletionHandler Behavior on Main vs Background thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, completionhandler

Does the thread from which a method is being used matter in terms of completionHandlers? When running on the Main thread, I have no problems; the `(data) in` completionHandler is called and thus the function's completionHandler within that.

The following is my code:

```
  static func getInfo(user: User,completion: (([String:String]) -> Void)? = nil){
      
       print(user.apiUid)
       var enrolledCourses: [String:String] = [:]
       
       NetworkingManager.staticGeneralRequest(withEndpoint: someURL, oauthToken: user.oauth_token, oauthTokenSecret: user.oauth_token_secret) { (data) in
           let decodedData: [String:String] = data.getData()
           completion?(decodedData)
       }
     
   }

//NOTE: According to the compiler, 
//the use of an optional completionHandler means that it's `@escaping` by default.
```

Is this an issue pretaining to threading, and what are some best practices to ensure that code works well across threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closure was deallocated before you get the response. Adding `@escaping` like this: `static func getInfo(user: User, completion: @escaping (([String:String]) -> Void)? = nil)` to keep it in scope.

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error: `Closure is already escaping in optional type argument`. That means that it's already `@escaping`

Comment: Can you show more code inside the NetworkingManager class?

Comment: Sure, one second

Comment: Hosting it here: https://github.com/cyrussinc/testPlayground/blob/main/playground.swift

Comment: I resolved the issue; I was calling from an unconventional context.